# How do I link Apps Script for loop to html?

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Still new to Google Apps Script and I'm struggling connecting my Apps Script to my html file. As you can see in my Apps Script code below I've created a loop within Apps Script and for each iteration of the for loop I'd like to create a new heading in the html script, hence the "<?= question =>" scriplet linking to the Apps Script. Can anyone help me here?

Apps Script:

```
const name = "Name"

//This is calling the html template
function doGet() {
  
  var ws = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var range_in_q = ws.getRange("A1:E" +  ws.getLastRow()).getValues();
  typeof(Logger.log(range_in_q));
  Logger.log(range_in_q.length);
  for (i = 0; i<range_in_q.length - 1; i++) {
      var questions = range_in_q[i + 1][0];
      var answers = range_in_q[i + 1][1];
      Logger.log(questions);
      Logger.log(answers);
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('index').evaluate();

  
  
  }
}


function includeExternalFile(filename) {
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile(filename).getContent();
}
```

Html Code:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1><?= name ?></h1>
    <? for (let i=0; i<test; i++){ ?>
    <h1> <?= questions ?></h1>
    <? } ?>
    <h1>This page was served through HtmlService!</h1>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you provide your expected situation? Because in your showing script, `answers` is not used while you are trying to use `questions`. So I cannot understand your expected situation. I apologize for this.

Answer (score 1):

#### Modification points:

- In your script, when `return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('index').evaluate();` is run in the loop, the function is finished.
- `name`, `questions` and `answers` are not used in `HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('index').evaluate()`.
- When the loop process is used in the HTML template, the process cost becomes high. [Ref (Author: myself)](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/f1436d88423077115d2c249862f12f17)

When these points are reflected in your script, how about the following modification?

#### Google Apps Script side:

```js
const name = "Name"

function doGet() {
  var ws = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var range_in_q = ws.getRange("A1:E" +  ws.getLastRow()).getValues();
  
  // I modified the below script.
  var questions = range_in_q.map(([a]) => `<h1>${a}</h1>`).join("");
  var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('index');
  html.name = name;
  html.questions = questions;
  return html.evaluate();
}
```

#### HTML side:

```html
<html>

<head>
  <base target="_top">
</head>

<body>
  <h1><?= name ?></h1>
  <?!= questions ?>
  <h1>This page was served through HtmlService!</h1>
</body>

</html>
```

- From your showing script, in this modification, `answers` is not used. Because I cannot know your expected situation using `answers`. Please be careful about this.

#### Note:

- **When you modified the Google Apps Script of Web Apps, please modify the deployment as a new version. By this, the modified script is reflected in Web Apps. Please be careful about this.**
- You can see the detail of this in my report "[Redeploying Web Apps without Changing URL of Web Apps for new IDE](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/ebf92d8f427d02d53989d6c3464a9c43)".

#### References:

- [HTML Service: Templated HTML](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates)
- [Benchmark: Process cost for HTML Template using Google Apps Script (Author: me)](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/f1436d88423077115d2c249862f12f17)

Comment: Tanaike, Posts have been deleted for having undisclosed self promotion. While everything in your link is extremely helpful and not spam, it may be considered as such, if you don't explicitly disclose that you're the author. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/348489/ See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/182212 for sample answer links, with proper disclosure.

Comment: @TheMaster Thank you for editing. I would like to use this in my answers as the template.

Comment: Hi Tanaike! Thank you so much! This is very helpful! I read your article on Process Costing. Per my understanding your solution has a html table created in the Apps Script which is showed in the HTML script. Therefore this lowers the process cost?

Comment: Hi Tanaike, In the line:
```var questions = range_in_q.map(([a]) => `<h1>${a}</h1>`).join("");```

What's this saying exactly? within array [a] if greater or equal to join array value with heading?

Comment: @bibby Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, from your reply, I couldn't understand your issue was resolved. Can I ask you about it?

Comment: @bibby About `Per my understanding your solution has a html table created in the Apps Script which is showed in the HTML script. Therefore this lowers the process cost?`, it's yes. In the current stage, when you want to add a HTML table to the HTML template, the process cost can be reduced by creating the HTML table in Google Apps Script, because of the high process cost of the HTML template.

Comment: @bibby About `In the line: var questions = range_in_q.map(([a]) => `<h1>${a}</h1>`).join(""); What's this saying exactly? within array [a] if greater or equal to join array value with heading?`, in this case, a value of `<h1>###</h1>` is created in an array, and an array is converted to the string value by `join("")`.